# Calculating Slope of 2 Points in the Same Row - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, statistics, linear-algebra

I have multiple rows of client data with 2 X and Y points of data within the same row. The points of data are a Performance KPI number for 2 different months.
Here are Headers:

Client ID | First Month (date) | First Month KPI ($) | Last Month (date) | Last Month KPI ($)| Slope (%)

I would like to add one more column for the slope between both points. Currently, the slope formula require the X and Y coordinates to be in their own columns. Is there a way to transform my data to use the slope formula in this case? Or is there a better way to calculate slope for each client?